# Jinja - Nested for statement inside of an if statement

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am trying to create a table that contains all of the records found inside of a query but only when the said query returns records.

```
{% if l > 0 %}
{% for record in precord %}
    <tr> 
        <td colspan=1>{{ record['date'] }}</td>
        <td colspan=2>{{ record['tasknote'] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3><center>No previous contacts. Get working!</center></td>
    </tr>
{% endif %}
```

`l` is equal to the amount of records found. I have tested this by calling `l` inside of the `if` loop and it does/doesn't fire based upon the correct amount of records.

My issue is I am not able to get the table row to print. It works perfectly fine without the count test, but as soon as I add the wrapper it doesn't. I feel like I am missing a syntax error, but I've looked through the documentation and can't seem to find out what is going on.

Edited to add code that renders template:

```
@app.route('/view/<id>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def view(id):
    form = CreatePR()
    record = people.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})
    precord = history.find({"parentRecord": str(record['_id'])}).sort('date',pymongo.ASCENDING)
    listl = len(list(precord))

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('view.html', form=form, people=record, precord=precord, auth=current_user.is_authenticated, id=id, l=listl)
    
    elif request.method == "POST":
        date = request.form.get('date')
        tasknote = request.form.get('tasknote')
        adate = datetime.today()
        
        history.insert_one({"date": date, "tasknote": tasknote, "dateAdded": adate.strftime("%x"), "parentRecord": id})
        flash('Your record has been added successfully.')
        return redirect(url_for('view', id=id))
```

Comment: You need to provide code that renders this template and reproduces the behavior you're asking about; otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: Just added, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a specific construct for this type of case: Jinja does have a `for ... else ...` implementation:

```
{% for record in precord | default([], true) %}
  <tr> 
    <td colspan="1">{{ record.date }}</td>
    <td colspan="2">{{ record.tasknote }}</td>
  </tr>
{% else %}
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <center>No previous contacts. Get working!</center>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is always showing the 'No previous contacts...' now. I am using MongoDB so in my tests, it does not output None when using find().

Comment: This means `precord` is either an empty object or array, then.

Comment: Certainly -is there a way to modify the above code to make it work with a MongoDB find() method?

Comment: This worked when I removed the `listl = len(list(precord))`. It seems like using the list function changed the format and prevented it from being included in a for statement.